# How do I install and use gdb inside a docker?

Tags: python, docker, gdb, gdbserver

I used the following code in docker but that didnt work

```
RUN mkdir gdb-build ;\
    cd gdb-build;\
    wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.11.tar.xz;\
    tar -xvf gdb-7.11.tar.xz;\
    cd gdb-7.11;\
    ./configure --prefix=/usr;\
    make;\
    make -C gdb install;\
    cd ..;\
    rm -rf gdb-build/;
```

But its says this when i run it the output is this:

```
Connecting to ftp.gnu.org (208.118.235.20:80)
gdb-7.11.tar.xz        0% |                               |   182k  0:01:40 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz        5% |*                              |  1060k  0:00:32 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       10% |***                            |  1876k  0:00:26 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       14% |****                           |  2694k  0:00:23 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       19% |*****                          |  3569k  0:00:20 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       23% |*******                        |  4385k  0:00:19 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       28% |********                       |  5200k  0:00:17 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       32% |**********                     |  6079k  0:00:16 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       37% |***********                    |  6894k  0:00:15 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       41% |************                   |  7710k  0:00:13 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       46% |**************                 |  8568k  0:00:12 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       50% |***************                |  9369k  0:00:11 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       55% |*****************              | 10219k  0:00:10 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       59% |******************             | 11029k  0:00:09 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       64% |*******************            | 11907k  0:00:08 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       68% |*********************          | 12723k  0:00:07 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       73% |**********************         | 13538k  0:00:06 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       77% |************************       | 14417k  0:00:05 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       82% |*************************      | 15232k  0:00:04 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       87% |***************************    | 16111k  0:00:02 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       91% |****************************   | 16926k  0:00:01 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz       95% |*****************************  | 17742k  0:00:00 ETA
gdb-7.11.tar.xz      100% |*******************************| 18490k  0:00:00 ETA

tar (child): xz: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
/bin/sh: cd: line 1: can't cd to gdb-7.11
/bin/sh: ./configure: not found
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** gdb: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

The files is downloaded but why does it still say no such file or directory?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to McGrady. I just had to add `xz-utils`to the container. for alpine it is `RUN apk add xz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tar (child): xz: Cannot exec: No such file or directory`

The above error message doesn't mean there is no such file called `gdb-7.11.tar.xz`.It means it can't find `xz` compression tools:

So you need to install the `xz` compression tools, for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install xz-utils
```

Comment: Thanks @McGrady I am using alpine in my docker. what is the package for `xz-utils` in alpine?

Comment: @ramcharanVenkat Maybe you can try `xz`,have a look at [buildpack-deps on Alpine Linux](https://hub.docker.com/r/praekeltfoundation/alpine-buildpack-deps/)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also just do

```
sudo apt-get install gdb
```